# Not parsing the array from json to android java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

Why is it not parsing the array from json to android java, please help me to solve this problem ? I want to show it's list view. How can i achieve this?

```
String strJson="{\"Employee\":[{\"id\":\"101\",\"name\":\"Pushkar\",\"salary\":\"5000\"},{\"id\":\"102\",\"name\":\"Rahul\",\"salary\":\"4000\"},{\"id\":\"103\",\"name\":\"tanveer\",\"salary\":\"56678\"}]}";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        final ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<Employee> employ = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        String data;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
             //jsonArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
             // Log.d("jsonArrayLength: ", "Length: "+ jsonObject.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                String salary = jsonObject.getString("salary");
                emp.setId(id);
                emp.setName(name);
                emp.setSalary(salary);
                item.add(i,name);
                employ.add(i,emp);
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I want to show it's list view.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using jsonObject in for loop. You need to get Employee jsonArray from that object and than iterate through it to get employee list as -

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Employee");
        Log.d("jsonArrayLength: ", "Length: "+ jsonArr.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            JSONObject empObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = empObj.getString("name");
            String id = empObj.getString("id");
            String salary = empObj.getString("salary");
            emp.setId(id);
            emp.setName(name);
            emp.setSalary(salary);
            item.add(i,name);
            employ.add(i,emp);
        }

    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it worked out.
Thank you :) @AlayaGíłł